# Elasticsearch when a file system goes read-only

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a 3 node Elasticsearch cluster, running 1.7.3. Every node is both a data and master node. Last night, one of the machines corrupted its file system and re-mounted it read-only. From that point, the cluster returned errors on insertion, like

```
RemoteTransportException[[db06][inet[/IPREMOVED:9300]][indices:data/write/index]]; nested: IndexFailedEngineException[[messages_201503071849][1] Index failed for [message#586279]]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/data/nodes/0/indices/messages_201503071849/1/index/_1v70.fdx (Read-only file system)];
```

Is there any way to configure the system to handle this error better (ie. for that node to take itself out of the cluster)? We want to be able to continue with writes in this situation.

Comment: To remove by itself from the cluster I don't think so...

Comment: So how do people deal with this such that the cluster can continue to accept writes?

Comment: you could create a cron job to kill the node if the fs is read only

Comment: What is your `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` settings value?

Comment: My discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes is 2.

Comment: There is data on that node that you don't want it to be lost. So I guess new writes are now sent to the other cluster nodes and once this node is healthy again Elasticsearch will continue from where it stopped. I think like @Andrei Stefan that there is no other way to deal with what you describe in Elasticsearch

Comment: It does not make sense to keep a read only node. So why not just shut it down with some monitor or trigger system.Then ES will remove it from cluster and write data to the remain nodes.

Comment: Can you check the user permissions to your data directory? Its possible that when the drive was mounted post corruption, it might have not been granted write access to the user who reads/writes (usually `elasticsearch` if running as a service).

Answer (score 1):

Actually reading from several places (mainly ElasticSearch's forum) it appears that Elastic nodes have no way to recover by themselves of this error, and even worse, the cluster will lock itself in case of a failure.

The reason why this happens (from [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cluster-locks-up-if-master-node-filesystem-becomes-read-only/38245/3)):

> The reason why ES is not shutting down automatically is because
>   org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnviroment keeps a java.nio.file.FileStore
>   which is never monitored by calling isReadOnly() method regularly.

See [the same post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cluster-locks-up-if-master-node-filesystem-becomes-read-only/38245/3) for 2 possible solutions